# How to check and monitor activity logs in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I wish to know if there is any way to get detailed logs of activities done on a RabbitMQ cluster. 
Activities include - If I add or remove a binding to an Exchange, When was these bindings added/deleted ? Who created the bhindings ? When was exchange/queue created ? When was a queue/exchange' modified ? Any activities done related to exchanges/queues.. are these logged somewhere and can we see it on UI or through command line?

I tried to monitor these details over RabbitMQ UI - localhost:15672, but could not see any such details except message related metrics.

Comment: Check the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RabbitMQ Event Exchange plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html) exists for this reason. You will have to write an application to consume these events.